# Rotate, Flip and Resize icons in Kendo UI Mobile

Tags: icons, kendo-mobile

Is it possible to rotate (90-180-270 degrees), flip (horizontal/vertical) and resize (2x, 3x) icons easily in kendo-ui mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do rotate easily with CSS transforms, something like this:

```
<style>
    .km-home:after {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
</style>
```

You can flip an element with CSS transforms too:

```
<style>
    .km-home:after {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
        transform: scaleX(-1);
    }
</style>
```

You can also use scale to resize it - scale(2), etc...

However this question has nothing to do with Kendo UI :)

Comment: thank you very much. I hoped there were some commands on the html side like data-icon-size=  . But this is also easy. Thanks again

Comment: transform: scaleX(-1) is the best solution because rotate(180deg) can have undesirable results in which the icon is offset since the .km-icon:before and .km-icon:after pseudo-elements are usually positioned in a manner that doesn't rotate with the icon's visual center point.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example implementation of previous and next buttons using a custom kendo mobile icon based on Bundyo's insights:

```
<a data-role="button" class="prev" data-icon="custom"></a>
<a data-role="button" class="next" data-icon="custom"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.km-button.prev .km-icon.km-custom:before, .km-button.prev .km-icon.km-custom:after, 
.km-button.next .km-icon.km-custom:before, .km-button.next .km-icon.km-custom:after { content: "\e217" }
.km-button.prev .km-icon.km-custom:before, .km-button.prev .km-icon.km-custom:after { -moz-transform: scaleX(-1); -ms-transform: scaleX(-1); -o-transform: scaleX(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); transform: scaleX(-1); }
```